# WPF - Bind image property to Image control

Tags: wpf, data-binding, image

Suppose I have **string Name** and **Image Photo** as properties of a class in my DataContext. I need to bind them to controls is a DataTemplate.

I thought this would work but it doesn't:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Photo}"/>
```

Why not? Should I my Photo have another type? (BitmapImage perhaps?)

How can I bind an Image control to an Image property?

Thanks!

Edit: As usual, after clicking submit I saw that the error is very clear: there's no converter from Image to ImageSource. How would my converter be to convert Image to ImageSource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really makes sense to have a data property of type Image, since Image is a control (if you really want to do that you could bind to Photo.Source). You should use an ImageSource instead (or a BitmapImage, like you did, since BitmapImage inherits from ImageSource).

Comment: I agree Thomas. I started with type Image because for no good reason. :) It wasn't a good idea at all.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if I make my property BitmapImage it all works just fine.
Sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: There are no stupid questions! :) Hope it solved your problem!